# Pure virtual methods in C#?

Tags: c#, abstract-class, pure-virtual

I've been told to make my class abstract:

```
public abstract class Airplane_Abstract
```

And to make a method called move virtual

```
 public virtual void Move()
        {
            //use the property to ensure that there is a valid position object
            double radians = PlanePosition.Direction * (Math.PI / 180.0);

            // change the x location by the x vector of the speed
            PlanePosition.X_Coordinate += (int)(PlanePosition.Speed * Math.Cos(radians));

            // change the y location by the y vector of the speed
            PlanePosition.Y_Coordinate += (int)(PlanePosition.Speed * Math.Sin(radians));
        }
```

And that 4 other methods should be "pure virtual methods."
What is that exactly?

They all look like this right now:

```
public virtual void TurnRight()
{
    // turn right relative to the airplane
    if (PlanePosition.Direction >= 0 && PlanePosition.Direction < Position.MAX_COMPASS_DIRECTION)
        PlanePosition.Direction += 1;
    else
        PlanePosition.Direction = Position.MIN_COMPASS_DIRECTION;  //due north
}
```

Comment: When interested, for a discussion on pure virtual and non-pure virtual functions (advantages and disadvantages), I will selfishly redirect to [a blog post](http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2010/12/20/abstraction-is-everything/) of me. :)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

My guess is that whoever told you to write a "pure virtual" method was a C++ programmer rather than a C# programmer... but the equivalent is an abstract method:

```
public abstract void TurnRight();
```

That forces concrete subclasses to override `TurnRight` with a real implementation.

Comment: So does that mean every bit of content it has should be taken out? o.o That's what its looking like.

Comment: @allthosemiles: For the abstract methods, yes. The point of an abstract method is that it *doesn't* have a body.

Comment: pure virtual is a [general name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#Abstract_classes_and_pure_virtual_functions), and not language specific

Comment: @Steven: Hmm... possibly, but I've only *ever* seen it in the context of C++ before. I suspect anyone talking about them is likely to have a C++ background :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I'm guilty there. :) Maybe it simply originated from C++.

Comment: @Steven: Yup, I think that's almost certainly the explanation.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Just out of curiosity, I [asked the question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/46004/15464) on Programmers.SE. :)

Comment: @Steven: Thanks - it'll be interesting to see what comes out of it.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Seems you were right. It also seems there is a lack of consistent naming, although I did find a scientific article which tries to generalize some terms. Oh, and probably someone should edit wikipedia. :)

Answer (score 13):

"Pure virtual" is C++ terminology. The C# equivalent is an abstract method.

Answer (score 11):

They probably mean that the methods should be marked `abstract`.

```
 public abstract void TurnRight();
```

You will then need to implement them in the subclasses, as opposed to an empty virtual method, where the subclass would not have to override it.

Answer (score 8):

A pure virtual function is terminology of C++ but in C# if a function which is implemented in Derived class and that derived class is not an Abstract class.

```
abstract class PureVirtual
{
    public abstract void PureVirtualMethod();
}

class Derivered : PureVirtual
{
    public override void PureVirtualMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm pure virtual function");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Or even you can go interface, thought some little limitation is required:

```
public interface IControllable
{
    void Move(int step);
    void Backward(int step);
}

public interface ITurnable
{
   void TurnLeft(float angle);
   void TurnRight(float angle);
}

public class Airplane : IControllable, ITurnable
{
   void Move(int step)
   {
       // TODO: Implement code here...
   }
   void Backward(int step)
   {
       // TODO: Implement code here...
   }
   void TurnLeft(float angle)
   {
       // TODO: Implement code here...
   }
   void TurnRight(float angle)
   {
       // TODO: Implement code here...
   }
}
```

However, you will have to **implement all** the function declaration of both `IControllable` and `ITurnable` have assigned, otherwise an compiler error will occur. If you want optional virutal implementation, you would have to go `abstract class` for virtual method with `interface` for pure virtual method.

In fact, there is a difference between `interface` function and `abstract` function, that **`interface` only declares function**, all `interface` function have to go all public so there's no fancy class property such as `private` or `protected` so it's very fast, while `abstract` function are **actual class method without implementation** and **forces the implementation in the derived class**, so you can put `private`, `protected` and access member variables with `abstract` functions, and most of the time **it's slower because the class inheritance relations are analyzed in run time**. (aka vtable)

Answer (score 2):

You then don't have an implementation in the Airplane_Abstract Class but are forcing consumers "inheritors" of the Class to implement them.

The Airplane_Abstract Class is unusable until you inherit and implement the abstract functions.

Answer (score -2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function

"In object-oriented programming, a virtual function or virtual method is a function or method whose behaviour can be overridden within an inheriting class by a function with the same signature."

Google is always your friend.

Comment: This is not an answer, as it describes a virtual, not a pure virtual method. A pure virtual method has no implementation and thus must be overridden rather than can be overridden.